# How to get second half of a number?

Tags: c++, math

If n is a given number, how to get the first half of a number and second half?
Ex: 9456, what I need is the first half is 94 and the second half is 56.

I can get the first half of a number using `(int)(n / pow(10, (digits / 2)))` this formula, but am not able to get the second half. Can anyone help here?
Thank you.

Comment: `value % 100 `?

Comment: What would be the "second half" of `123`?  Or of `1`?

Comment: Don't involve `pow`, or any other floating point operations, in integer problems.

Comment: Assuming the value has an integral type with a value between `1000` and `9999` inclusive (i.e. it has four decimal digits when printed without leading zeros) consider what `value/100` and `value %100` give.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the simple process for picking up each digit using n%100 and then n/=10 ,then store the first half of numbers in a variable and the other half in another.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

```
first convert number to string , then use .length() to obtain max pow of 10 lets say = p.

then take phalf = p/2 if it is even or (p + 1)/2 , if it is odd.

then do divide and modulo with pow( 10, phalf ), divide will give upper first half and modulo woill give lower second half.
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the MSB (most significant digit), you have to use / operator.
and to get the LSB (least significant digit), you have to use % operator.

In your case :
second_half = n % pow(10, digits / 2)

Make sure to round the outcome of the pow function since, it return type is double, which may lead to precision error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer doesn't account for cases where `n` has an odd number of digits. Since the OP has never replied to any comments asking for clarification you can simply add a caveat or note to your answer to the effect that *n is assumed to contain an even number of digits*.